# When opening word file "/" doesn't work but "\\" does (package os in python)

Tags: python, operating-system

Create a `main.py` file and a `test.docx` file in the parent directory.

This works:

```py
import os

os.startfile("..\\test.docx")
```

This does not

```py
import os

os.startfile("../test.docx")
```

It returns

```py
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '../test.docx'
```

What's even more surprising is that `/` works in other contexts, e.g.

```py
print(os.listdir("../"))
```

does return a list with `test.docx` in it.

I'm using `Windows 11`, `Python 3.11.1` and `Pycharm 2022.3`

Comment: Maybe use `os.sep` and don't rely on forward slash / backslash to work or not?

Comment: The question is why does this happen. OP clearly has already found a solution to make the function work.

Comment: `os.startfile(f"..{os.sep}test.docx")` does work indeed, but what I find weird is the inconsistency between two functions of the SAME package (`os.listdir` and `os.startfile`)

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering, I've figured out that there is a requirement to put a slash somewhere in the relative path:

```
>>> os.startfile(".\/test.docx")  # Works
>>> os.startfile(".\./test.docx")  # Works
>>> os.startfile("./.\\./test.docx")  # Works
>>> os.startfile("././.\\./test.docx")  # Works
>>> os.startfile("./test.docx\\")  # Even this works

>>> os.startfile("./././test.docx")  # Fails
```

This seems to be some undocumented behavior of the Windows API. Looking at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile), we can see that all the `.startfile()` function does is [run `ShellExecuteW` under the hood](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c49da0cb7434c676d70b9ccf38aca82ac0d64a9/Modules/posixmodule.c#L11237).

Going to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#canonicalize-separators), we can see that the forward slash shouldn't matter, as it would be converted into a backslash.

Comment: There is a requirement to put a backward slash somewhere? And it will be ignored but will allow the code to run?

Comment: It won't be ignored, it will be part of the path. However, there are ways to make it unnecessary, such as `.\./test.docx` (this works). Here, I am accessing the current directory, using a backslash, then accessing the current directory again using the forward slash (`/`). Theoretically, if I removed the `.\`, it should work, since the rest (`./`) would still be pointing to the current directory. However, this is not the case for some reason. The official Microsoft documentation seems to be misleading here, so my guess is that the documentation is written wrong.